# How to store the ids of options in an array of a select box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<select id="s1">
  <option value="volvo" id="o1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" id="o2">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" id="o3">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" id="o4">Audi</option>
</select>    

<select id="s2">
  <option value="Toyota" id="o5">Toyota</option>
  <option value="Porsche" id="o6">Porsche</option>
  <option value="Suzuki" id="o7">Suzuki</option>
  <option value="Mahindra" id="o8">Mahindra</option>
</select>
```

I want to create an array which stores the id of the selected option. Each selected option is stored in an array in such a way that it removes the previous id of the option and replaces it with the new one. If I change an option the previous id should be removed and replaced with the new one. Since there are two select boxes, at the end, the array should contain two ids i.e ids of the two options.

Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a change eventListener to your select boxes and store the values from both boxes in your array.

```
var values = ["", ""];

document.getElementById("s1").addEventListener("change", changed);
document.getElementById("s2").addEventListener("change", changed);

function changed(e) {
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case "s1":
      values[0] = document.getElementById("s1").value;
      break;
    case "s2":
      values[1] = document.getElementById("s2").value;
      break;
  }
  console.log(values);
}
```

If you want to know the id of an option instead of it's value you can use this function instead:

```
function changed(e) {
  var element;
  switch (e.target.id) {
    case "s1":
      element = document.getElementById("s1");
      values[0] = element[element.selectedIndex].id;
      break;
    case "s2":
      element = document.getElementById("s2");
      values[1] = element[element.selectedIndex].id;
      break;
  }
  console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: I want the ids of the options not values.

Comment: And what if there are n number of select boxes? Just asking.

Comment: I refined my answer to take care of ids. My honest apologize, I misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the best solution haha.
But I can only think in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var v1 = {
    's1': 0,
    's2': 0
  }
  var teste = 0;

  $(".select").change(function(e){

    v1[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('id');

    console.log(v1);

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1" class="select">
  <option value="volvo" id="o1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" id="o2">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" id="o3">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" id="o4">Audi</option>
</select>    

<select id="s2" class="select">
  <option value="Toyota" id="o5">Toyota</option>
  <option value="Porsche" id="o6">Porsche</option>
  <option value="Suzuki" id="o7">Suzuki</option>
  <option value="Mahindra" id="o8">Mahindra</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want the ids like if I select Volvo then it should display o1.

Comment: Edited my friend.
Change the .val() to .children("option:selected").attr('id') It will seek the selected option ID